# Table formatting in java itextpdf

Tags: java, string, pdf, formatting, itext

I have problem with table formatting in itextpdf java-framework. I made a table with String.format

```
String.format("|%-20s| %-20s| %-20s| %-30s| %-20s|\n\n",
                    userDTO.getUserId(),
                    userDTO.getName(), userDTO.getSecondName(),
                    userDTO.getEmail().trim(), userDTO.getContracts()))
```

It looks well.

But, when i try to insert this string to pdf

```
document.add(new Paragraph(String.format("|%-20s| %-20s| %-20s| %-30s| %-20s|\n\n",
                    userDTO.getUserId(),
                    userDTO.getName(), userDTO.getSecondName(),
                    userDTO.getEmail(), userDTO.getContracts())));
```

Formatting changes.
[image: problem pic]

How should i repair table?

**UPD**

Solution: use  PdfPTable

```
    PdfPTable tb = new PdfPTable(3);
    tb.addCell(userDTO.getUserId());
    tb.addCell(userDTO.getName());
    tb.addCell(userDTO.getEmail());
    document.add(tb);
```

Comment: Please use the iText `PdfPTable` class.

Comment: Your approach to use spaces to position text is wrong. You should use either tabs or (better yet) a table. If you insist on using spaces to position text, you should at least use a monospaced font (*not* a proportional font such as Helvetica).

Comment: mkl, thank you! I solved my problem. Moderator set my topic as a duplicated. But suggested topic about c#. How can i change this status?